# How to bypass the login page for an outdated open source project that utilized OpenID?

Tags: java, security, authentication, tomcat, openid

I am currently running an instance of Zuul (https://github.com/confluex/zuul) on my localhost utilizing Tomcat 8.5. Zuul is an open source properties file manager software that stopped being maintained around 2015. When I try to access any of the user authentication links on the login page they return a 500 HTTPS Status.
([Image of Login Providers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqKl8.png))
It appears that each of the authentication providers have shut down their services. However, the authentication method seems to utilize j_spring_security_check. I have not had much luck researching how this authentication works, but the errors logged are listed below.

```
09-Jul-2021 14:01:31.716 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-27] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatch] in context with path [/my_zuul] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/cyberneko/html/HTMLTagBalancingListener
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.parseDocument(CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.java:99)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.getHtmlMeta(CyberNekoDOMYadisHtmlParser.java:42)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.getHtmlMeta(YadisResolver.java:325)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.retrieveXrdsLocation(YadisResolver.java:453)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:252)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:232)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver.discover(YadisResolver.java:166)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:147)
    at org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery.discover(Discovery.java:129)
    at org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager.discover(ConsumerManager.java:542)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenID4JavaConsumer.beginConsumption(OpenID4JavaConsumer.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.openid.OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIDAuthenticationFilter.java:123)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:201)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:544)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:698)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:364)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:616)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:831)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1629)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If anyone has any recommendations on how to bypass the authentication system, fix it, or any documentation links, they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Update: The nekohmtl.jar file was missing from the class path which solved the 500 response. Now I am continuing to receive a 401 Response. The command line output is listed below:

Comment: [07-12 12:32:44] INFO  Discovery [http-nio-8080-exec-30]: Discovered 0 OpenID endpoints.
[07-12 12:32:44] ERROR ConsumerManager [http-nio-8080-exec-30]: Association attempt, but no discovey endpoints provided.
[07-12 12:32:44] INFO  OpenIdRegistrationHandler [http-nio-8080-exec-30]: Creating new account unregistered user for auth: null